# Why can't I get both of these lines to show up in this plotly chart?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Here is my code

```
fig = plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_lines(
    x = 1:200
    , y = (rnorm(200) %>% cumsum) + 10
    , name = "left side"
    , line = list(color = "black")
    , yaxis = "y"
  ) %>% add_trace(
    x = seq(1, 200, by = 10)
    , y = rnorm(20) + 100
    , name = "right side"
    , yaxis = "y2"
  ) %>% layout(
    yaxis = list(
      side = "left"
      , zeroline = FALSE
    )
    , yaxis2 = list(
      side = "right"
      , zeroline = FALSE
    )
  )
fig
```

All I see is a single line for the "right side".

I am running on windows. Ultimately I want this as part of a shiny app which I will be sharing with others as an R project.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it always happen that I ponder over a question for a long time before giving in and posting a question, only for me to realise the answer shortly thereafter?

Apparently I need to specify the `overlaying` argument for the second axis.

```
, yaxis2 = list(
      side = "right"
      , overlaying = "y"
    )
```